# HDMI port not detected in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, hardware, display, hdmi

I purchased a new Lenovo ideapad 3, Core i7 decent laptop with Linux Mint. Had to backwards install Centos 7 to run an AWIPS weather program. Now the HDMI external port to run an external monitor doesn't do anything as well as being able to see a Bluetooth mouse. Laptop says Intel IRIS Plus graphics. Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Centos 7 has a very outdated kernel which likely doesn't support your hardware.

Please use something newer/fresher.

Comment: not an option with the software i need to use.

Comment: You can perfectly install CentOS in chroot or VM.